# Trying to show that $ \int_\gamma f(z) dz = 2\pi i$ in MatLab but getting an incorrect answer?

Tags: complex-analysis, numerical-methods, matlab

Let $\gamma$ be the unit circle in the complex plane. I am trying to show in MatLab that for $f(z) = 1/z$ we have

$$
\int_\gamma f(z) dz = 2\pi i,
$$

However I get (effectively) zero as my answer when I run the code. I am using a periodic trapezoidal/midpoint rule for the quadrature on the contour.

```
tN = 2^5;
t = 2*pi*(0:tN-1)'/tN;
z = exp(1i*t);
dz = 1i*exp(1i*t);
w = (2*pi/tN)*dz;

f_z = 1./z;

int_f_z = w' * f_z;
disp(int_f_z)
```

Does anyone know why this is not returning the correct answer?

Comment: what output are you getting?

Comment: @ncmathsadist I get $-2.4980 \times 10^{-16} + 5.5511 \times 10^{-17}i$ which is around machine precision so effectively zero.

Comment: @eurocoder What is $w'$?

Comment: @RobertZ the transpose of $w$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as though you're calculating
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{T_n} \frac 1{\exp\left(\frac{2 \pi (k-1)}{T_n}\,i\right)} \cdot \frac{2 \pi}{T_n} \approx \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac 1{z(t)}\,dt
$$
where $z(t) = \exp(it)$.  What you should instead be calculating is
$$
\int_\gamma \frac 1z \,dz = \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac 1{z(t)} \frac{dz}{dt}\,dt
$$

Comment: @Ommmmm Ok I have corrected for that but it still does not give the correct answer. I have edited my post to include the correction. Now it gives $1.5266\times 10^{-16}$. Any ideas?

Comment: @eurocoder the problem is that `'` doesn't just take the transpose; it takes the *conjugate-transpose*.  Use `w.'*f_z` instead.

Comment: @Ommmmm Great it works!

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to implement the term $dz$. 
Try by replacing

> int_f_z = w' * f_z

with

> int_f_z = w' * f_z * 1i*z.